# Is it possible to let caller to pay for the cpu of an inline deferred transaction of a contract?

Tags: eosio-code

For example, A send a transaction t1 that will call the contract action act1, act1 will send a deferred transaction t2. Is it possilbe that let A
pay for the cpu instead of the contract account?

Comment: No it isn't. And deferred transactions are deprecated and not supported anymore.